# How to prevent changes to an IReadOnlyList<T>?

Tags: c#, readonly-collection

I need to use `IReadOnlyList<T>` as a return parameter since it matches best my needs, but as you can see in the examples below, you can still modify the list it wraps if it is not truly read-only.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        // return an IReadOnlyList that wraps a List, we can modify content
        var list1 = GetList1();
        if (list1 is List<Section> sections1) // can be true
        {
            sections1.Clear();
        }

        // return an IReadOnlyList that wraps an ImmutableArray, we cannot modify content
        var list2 = GetList2();
        if (list2 is List<Section> sections2) // never true
        {
            sections2.Clear();
        }
    }

    public static IReadOnlyList<Section> GetList1()
    {
        return new List<Section> {new Section()};
    }

    public static IReadOnlyList<Section> GetList2()
    {
        return ImmutableArray.Create(new Section());
    }
}

public struct Section
{
}
```

**Problem:**

`ImmutableArray<T>` looks great as it is truly read-only, the only thing is I don't want/need to publicly return that [fully-featured class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=netcore-2.2) that allows changes that produces a copy.

I therefore stick to return `IReadOnlyList<T>` since it's intent is simple but I need to fix the possibly modifiable list issue.

**Question:**

Is returning an `ImmutableArray<T>` as an `IReadOnlyList<T>` is the right approach ?

If not then can you suggest on how to do it ?

Comment: Remember that `IReadOnlyList` doesn't "wrap" anything. It's still the same list object. `List` implements `IReadOnlyList` and that's how you're accessing it. It's like putting a cover on your phone that hides the bottom half of the screen - it's still the same phone. I would say `ImmutableArray` is the correct way to approach this if you want to do more than stop people accidentally modifying the list.

Comment: Okay, it's not the right term to use !

Comment: Sorry, going to edit my question because I forgot to mention something.

Comment: If you don’t expose the original list you can use the AsReadOnly method, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.asreadonly?view=netframework-4.7.2 which creates a wrapper that has only the read-only collection methods.

Comment: @ckuri Take a look at remarks section in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Aybe That’s why I said "If you don’t expose the original list". If you do `new List<Section> { … }.AsReadOnly()` you will get a read-only list which can’t be changed in any way, because you can’t get hold of the original modifiable list anymore.

Comment: Right, doing so will effectively work, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how `IReadOnlyList` works

[IReadOnlyList Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The `IReadOnlyList<T>` represents a list in which the number and order
>   of list elements is read-only. **The content of list elements is not
>   guaranteed to be read-only**.

If you want an `Immutable` `Collection` check out

[System.Collections.Immutable Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable(v=vs.111).aspx)

> The System.Collections.Immutable namespace contains interfaces and
>   classes that define immutable collections.